# IBus 1.4.1 input switch major lag (xubuntu 12.04)

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, language-support, ibus

I am absolutely sure it's an **IBus** problem. It doesn't want to switch, lagging for a few minutes up to an hour, from any language to any language. It is selected as the Keyboard Input Method System and starts on log-in.

- (*I have Japanese `anthy` and `mozc` installed, along with default - it absolutely refuses to use `mozc` though*).

It doesn't matter if you're using a **keyboard shortcut**, **embedded-in-toolbar-icon menu**, **IBus preferences**, or **floating selector** in the corner of your screen.

This is driving me nuts. In fact, the only method I've found is basically cheating:

- switch to `Anthy`, go do something for half an hour, and **if** `Anthy` decides to initialize I get to use its Latin input option (that's buggy and gives random double-width spaces, etc).
- Is there any way to get it to reliably switch between input options in, like, 10 seconds or less (or at least show me a g-d progress bar)?
- If not, is there another input method? (SCIM, UIM, PRIME keep coming up but I don't want to install things willy-nilly)

Comment: I installed the ibus-mozc package, and can't reproduce the problem you describe. For me it switches instantly. How do you launch IBus? Have you picked IBus in Language Support and let it be started automatically at login? By doing so, a couple of related environment variables are set automatically which may prevent problems. (I'm on 13.04, though.)

Comment: I just checked all of these. It launches on log-in, it is selected in language support. I installed mozc because I thought the problem might have been Anthy, I　don't care about mozc too much. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I can't edit my comment above... weird. I thought that turning on GNOME support on log-in might help (since IBus is gnome) but it didn't and froze my mouse, so I turned it off again.

Comment: Sounds like filing a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus would be a good idea.